# Python Error: iterator should return strings, not bytes (did you open the file in text mode?)

Tags: python

I am new to python and trying to write a function to load a csv data from a url. I have looked for various comfortable options like using pandas but am trying to do so using standard python available apis.

This is what I wrote using various online material but it gives me an error mentioned in the subject of the question

```
import csv
import requests
url="https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/pima-indians-diabetes/pima-indians-diabetes.data"
response=requests.get(url)
text=response.iter_lines()
reader=csv.reader(text,delimiter=',')
for row in reader:
    print(row)
```

How can change the row from byte to string ? str function does not work either.

This is not a duplicate question. If you look at the code, it does not use urllib and or contextlib or closing at all.  It just uses csv and requests modules. SInce csv.reader returns an iterable and you can start a for loop on the same, is it possible to change the row from bytes to strings **after** creating an iterator ?

SOLUTION

```
import csv
import requests
url="https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/pima-indians-diabetes/pima-indians-diabetes.data"
response=requests.get(url)
text=response.iter_lines(decode_unicode='utf-8')
reader=csv.reader(text,delimiter=',')
for row in reader:
    print(row)
```

This is what I was looking for, the solution is without importing codecs.

Comment: I think the duplicate question does have the solution you need. You just need to look past the first solution in the accepted answer. The second code block shows how you can use `codecs.iterdecode` to decode line by line. The second answer goes further to apply that method to a file being downloaded with `requests`, so you've got a complete solution.

Comment: @Blckknght - Thanks anyway for your suggestion, I was looking for a solution without importing codecs. I have edited the description.